# Verilog - Error: "Unresolved reference" when simulating

Tags: verilog, modelsim

Using ModelSim. I'm trying to simulate an up-down two-bit counter. It compiles fine, but when I try to run the simulation, I get the following error:

> ** Error: (vsim-3043) D:/ModelSim/examples/Lab7.v(46): Unresolved reference to 'state'.

Module is:

```
module TwoBitCounter(input Dir, clock, reset);

reg[1:0] state;

parameter S0 = 2'b00, S1=2'b01, S2=2'b10, S3 = 2'b11;

always @(posedge clock or negedge reset)
    if (reset == 0) state<=S0;

    else case(state)
        S0: if(Dir) state = S1; else state = S3;
        S1: if(Dir) state = S2; else state = S0;
        S2: if(Dir) state = S3; else state = S1;
        S3: if(Dir) state = S0; else state = S2;
    endcase

endmodule
```

Testbench is:

```
module Counter_TB;

reg Dir, clock, reset;


TwoBitCounter DA0(.Dir(Dir), .clock(clock), .reset(reset) );

initial begin

reset = 0;
Dir = 1;

#5 reset = 1;

forever #205 Dir = ~Dir;

end

initial begin
clock = 0;
forever #25 clock = ~clock;
end



initial #800 $stop;

initial $monitor ("State AB: %b", state);

endmodule
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `state` is an internal variable to the `TwoBitCounter` module, you get an error when you try to access it directly in the testbench module in the `$monitor` statement.  You can access it with a hierarchical specifier:

```
initial $monitor(DA0.state);
```

Or, you can declare `state` as an `output` port of the `TwoBitCounter` module and connect to it in the testbench.